# Webpack ExtractTextPlugin Error: Cannot resolve module '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to use ExtractTextPlugin but i can't solve this error.

Here is a fragment.

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            loader: [
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                        query: {
                            modules: true
                        }
                },
                'less-loader'
            ]
        })
    }
]
```

When I use

```
 loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?modules!less'),
```

It can work.

Comment: Which version of webpack are you using? The exact syntax depends on the version.

Comment: @demongolem Thank you. I use webpack 1.x and ExtractTextPlugin 1.x, so it wrong